# Display php array data in chart.js javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, chart.js

I'm trying to display a chart using chart.js, the chart data would be gotten from a php mysql database and displayed into the function below;

```
const pieChart2 = new Chart(document.getElementById('chats'), {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['John Mark', 'Sandra Friday', 'Kelvin Russel'], //php code to display data
    datasets: [{
      data: [25, 12, 4], //php code to display data
      backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true
  }
});
```

I am able to fetch data from my database

```
$rscht = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT users.name, COUNT(*) AS times FROM chat_logs INNER JOIN users ON chat_logs.sender_email = users.email GROUP BY chat_logs.sender_email ORDER BY times DESC");
```

I am also able to convert the data to a php array using jsonencode

```
<?php 
    $chatstack = array(); 
    while($userchat= mysqli_fetch_array($rscht)){
   
    $chatstackitem['label'] = $userchat['name'];
    $chatstackitem['value'] = $userchat['times'];
    array_push( $chatstack, $chatstackitem );
    }
    $chatArray = json_encode( $chatstack );
    print_r( $chatArray );

    ?>
```

The result above gives me

```
  <canvas id="chats"></canvas>
[{"label":"John Mark","value":"25"},{"label":"Sandra Friday","value":"12"},{"label":"Kelvin Russel","value":"4"}]
```

My question now is, how can I display the php code that shows all the array of names (label) in the labels: section

```
labels: ['John Mark', 'Sandra Friday', 'Kelvin Russel'], //php code to display data
```

and also display the php code that shows values in data section

```
 data: [25, 12, 4], //php code to display data
```

Comment: And your concrete question is? Have you checked everything for typos?

Comment: @hakre the question is whats the php code to display the labels and values where they are needed

Comment: So chart.js is working to your benefit and the problem is about extracting all the labels from the `$chatstack` array (of arrays)? Do you know about the [`array_column()` function](https://php.net/array_column) in PHP? _Example #1 Get the column of first names from a recordset_ there should you bring up-to-speed.

Comment: not really @hakre your assistance would be appreciated

Comment: the chat works perfectly. all I need to is enter the php code to pick up data from the database

Comment: Check _Example #1 Get the column of first names from a recordset_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the labels and data separately. You could create two  variables in your loop for this:

```
$chatLabels = []; 
$chatData = [];
while ($userchat= mysqli_fetch_array($rscht)) {
      $chatLabels[] = $userchat['name'];
      $chatData[] = $userchat['times'];
}
$chatLabelsJson = json_encode($chatLabels); // ["John Mark","Sandra Friday","Kelvin Russel"]
$chatDataJson = json_encode($chatData); //["25","12","4"]
```

Alternatively you could use `array_column` to pull out the data from your existing `$chatstack` array:

```
$chatLabels = array_column($chatstack, 'label');
$chatData = array_column($chatstack, 'value');
$chatLabelsJson = json_encode($chatLabels); // ["John Mark","Sandra Friday","Kelvin Russel"]
$chatDataJson = json_encode($chatData); //["25","12","4"]
```

Comment: Thank you all for assisting.

Answer (score 0):

So PHP is a backend server side technology, JS in this context is a client side only context. PHP will allow you to print this json encoded data into a script block that will allow you to assign this data to a JS variable.

Alternatively you could use a cookie to store this data and read it from there.